# Can a positive ion generator ionizing water create electricity with a net gain of electricity?

Tags: renewable-energy

Traditional ion generators work by sending electricity through air to ionize air with a negative charge. This is said to benefit human health. But, it should be possible to extract ions from atoms and turn the net charge positive. The idea is to get electricity out of the electrons and suck energy out of them. Is this possible and why or why not?

Comment: Re, "get electricity out of the electrons." I think that maybe you do not understand what "electricity" means. What you ask is somewhat akin to asking how we can get transportation out of cars, trucks, busses, ships, planes, trains, etc.

Comment: I mean electrons turned into energy

Comment: Electricity is not electrons turning into energy. When an electric battery delivers power to the bulb in a flashlight, the electrons flow in a _loop_, from the battery, through wires to the bulb, through the bulb, and back to the battery again. Alternating current (AC) power supplies are a bit more complicated, but the basic principle remains the same: The electrons _transport_ energy, but they do not _become_ energy.